# Symfony - Manually add errors to form collection

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, collections

I have to show the errors of a form before the form is submitted. 
To do that i added this piece of code to my action (right at the end of the action)

```
    if (!$form->isSubmitted()) {
        $validator = $this->get('validator');

        foreach ($validator->validate($form->getData()) as $violation) {
            $form->get($violation->getPropertyPath())->addError(new FormError($violation->getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this code doesn't work if i have a form collection embedded in the main form.

In this case, if i end up having an error on a field in the subform, the method `$violation->getPropertyPath()` returns something like `fieldName[0].subFormFieldName` which cannot be used to retrive the form field.

Does anyone have a solution??

Comment: why do you not use classic : 
`if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { ... }` ?

Comment: I do use `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { ... }` to add validation once the form is submitted, my problem is to add the validation messages also before the form is submitted.

Comment: It seems logical to not be able to validate if the form is not submitted... You need submit in order to process data to validate. Why do you need that ?

Comment: you should ask why to the designer who asked me to do it...i've spent a couple of hours trying to explain him that what he's asking is not logical, but it didn't work at all :-|
also i understand that the point is not to validate the form before is submitted, what i was trying to do is to validate the entity and for each violation append an error to the form (this form is quite a big form and can be halted at any point and resumed later, in this case it comes pre-populated with the data you previously inserted)

Comment: Arg, I'm sorry for that. But you can have two kind of submit-validation. I mean you can have a controller that submit the form and save it for later. You validation will accept blank field but will check the others. For the "real" submission you will have an other controller that will definitely submit the form and do others validations that avoid blank field. You should use validations groups to achieve that.

Comment: it's exactly what i did...2 different actions, the first just save whatever comes from the form, the second action validate on the real submit.
Regarding the form errors that i have to display before the submit, i'm using the code above and if the validation fail on a field which is part of `CollectionType` i just remove the broken collection. It's not the best thing to do, but i can't achieve anything better at the moment.